# ASP classic IsDate return wrong results

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I have probably problem with my IIS configuration.
Windows Server 2012 Foundation
IIS 8
Local system Czech, date format dd.mm.rr
ASP classic

```
IsDAte("18-10-13") - TRUE
IsDAte("18#10#13") - TRUE
IsDAte("18.10.13") - FALSE
IsDAte("18.10.2013") - TRUE
```

I need to IsDAte(18.10.13) return true. 
Why now IsDAte(18.10.13) return false?

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:**

The `isDate` check seems to return indifferent results with 2-digit year inputs, so you could use this function to check for valid dates:

```
function checkDate(datestr)
    dim temp, dt, d, m, y
    
    checkDate = false
    temp = split(datestr, ".")
    if UBound(temp) = 2 then
        d = CInt(temp(0))
        m = CInt(temp(1))
        y = CInt(temp(2))
        if y<100 then
            y = 2000 + y
        end if

        dt = DateSerial(y, m, d)
        if day(dt)=d and month(dt)=m then
            checkDate = true
        end if
    end if
end function
```

The DateSerial function call and the checks for day and month are inserted to make sure that invalid dates, such as 30.02.2013 will return false. It also supports 4-digit year inputs, but you should be aware that you will run into a Y3k issue with this function in a few hundred years. :)

---

As @Elie already said, isDate uses the current locale setting. But you can set the locale you want to match the required date format.

```
dim locale
' uses your current locale and will return false
Response.Write "<p>TEST: " & isDate("15.10.2013") & " --> " & GetLocale() & "</p>"

locale = GetLocale() ' save current locale
SetLocale(1031) ' de_AT

' uses de_AT locale and will return true
Response.Write "<p>TEST: " & isDate("15.10.2013") & " --> " & GetLocale() & "</p>"

SetLocale(locale) ' restore your locale
```

Find a [list of locale ids](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/active-server-pages/set-asp-locale-id-browser-language) to find the correct number

Comment: GetLocale return 1029 - > Czech

But on another PC with WIndows7 is GetLocale =1029 to and IsDAte("18.10.13") return FALSE  as well as IsDAte("18.10.2013") return TRUE

Comment: But why isDAte("18-10-13") return correct TRUE. There are only 2 digits as year too.

Comment: @user2886050: Well, my point is, if you cannot rely on the internal function (isDate), you have to do your own checking. I provided a sample for this, but if it does not meet your requirements, you can adapt it.

Comment: I know this was written 9-years ago, but the URL link (https://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_setlocale.asp#localeid) that you provide to obtain the list of locale IDs results in a 404 error.  However, after some searching, I found the list at the following URL: https://w3schools.sinsixx.com/vbscript/func_getlocale.asp.htm

Comment: Thanks for the hint @PaulScott I found a better link in MS docs

Answer (score 0):

The IsDate function uses local setting to determine if a string can be converted to a date.
More info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_isdate.asp).

I don't think that the date settings on Windows Server 2012 offer the "DD.MM.YY" option.